# App Store: How to setup a fixed price with a free trail

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I developed a Flutter app that I want to release commercially for iOS. I want to set up a one time purchase but offer the user a free trial before he has to pay.

Is there a way to release an App in this fashion without having to implement some logic in the app itself. All the information I find online makes me unsure on how to approach this.

As far as I know a fixed price is handeld entirely by apple and subscriptions have a trial option. Is there a way to combine the fixed price with a trial tho?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without implementing some logic.

This answer might help you achieve your goal:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722874

You need to setup 2 non-consumable in-app purchase products:

- First for trial with 0$ price
- Second non-consumable representing the paid 1-time purchase

Comment: You don't necessarily need the $0 initial in-app purchase. You can just track the first launch date and save it in the keychain and then require the paid IAP after a certain number of days have elapsed. Someone can get another free trial if they reset their phone but most people aren't going to go to that trouble